# How to close momentarily the android keyboard whatever EditText currently active

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-keypad

I have a form with various `EditText` and a confirm button,
I need that when the user click confirm whatever is the `EditText` that is currently used the keyboard will be momentarily closed, but if the user try to edit again one of the EditText the keyboard appears again.

How could I do this without add tons of codelines to control each `EditText` separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use simply the InputMethodManager

this way

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY, 0);
```

Comment: Perfect!  I'll accept your answer in after the 5 minutes countdown. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
 InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                //Find the currently focused view, so we can grab the correct window token from it.
 View view = getCurrentFocus();
//If no view currently has focus, create a new one, just so we can grab a window token from it
 if(view == null) {
    view = new View(this);
 }
inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

This will close the keybord, though i am not sure if keyboard will open gain for the same edit text, haven't tried that.